# Hybrid server-side-java and client-side-javascript charting library?

Tags: java, javascript, charts

Is there a library to generate same charts for the same data, both in Java and Javascript?

My task is both:

- display some flashy dynamic chart **in a browser**, better with dynamic tooltips, zooming and so on (I'm thinking Javascript here)
- and generate the same (or similar enough) charts on server side, in Java, for automatically sending them **in emails** (no browser at all in this scenario).

I'd like to avoid Flash for iPhone interoperability.

There are some static server-side charts like Eastwood/JFreeChart, but I'd like to make it more alive in browser.

Yes I can reload static images via Ajax. Are there other options?

Comment: What about [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)?  Unfortunately you'd have to render to a canvas in a browser to export it.  You could combine it with JFreeChart/Eastwood and have two graphs from the same data, although they'd look different.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331076/how-to-use-a-javascript-chart-library-like-d3-js-or-rapha%C3%ABl-in-server-side-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*How come this question is more than a year old but got no answers?! I suggest a rather questionable and somewhat hardcore approach.*

---

## Use JavaScript, it's awesome!

Here's your success formula: [`d3.js`](http://d3js.org/)`+`[`jsdom`](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#readme)`+`[`Rhino`](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)`+`[`Batik`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)

Specifically:

1. Generate your graphs using some slick JavaScript library like [d3.js](http://d3js.org/).
2. Use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#readme) to run d3 server-side. Jsdom is pure JS library and d3 is known to be working on top of it.
3. Run jsdom and d3 inside [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) - a JavaScript engine baked into your beloved JVM since 1.6 ([yay, JSR-223!](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pr/jsr223/index.html)). Although, I suggest you updating it to latest release ([It's on Maven Central, neat!](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mozilla/rhino/1.7R3)). I guess [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) can do a better job but I assume that you're stuck with Java.

   Also note that there's an older, more mature and Rhino-specific server-side DOM implementation - [EnvJs](http://www.envjs.com/) *([requires Rhino 1.7R2, not R3](http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/09/rhino-and-envjs/))*. You can try it if jsdom doesn't work for you.
4. Use [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) to rasterize an SVG generated by d3. [Batik even supports scripting inside SVG via Rhino.](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/scripting/ecmascript.html) That means you can generate interactive charts server-side if you want to. I also used it in practice and had great experience with it.

The whole approach [**is known to work** server-side with Node.JS as a JS engine and ImageMagick as a rasterizer](http://eng.wealthfront.com/2011/12/converting-dynamic-svg-to-png-with.html) but I see no reasons why it wouldn't work for you as well.

---

BTW, If you'll make it all running let me know.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! A pity I'm no longer on Grails project at all, this could be fun. `"If you'll make it all running let me know."` :D

Comment: Letting you know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557308/launch-jsdom-from-rhino-on-java

Comment: Wow! This is not "somewhat hardcore": it's 100% hardcore!

Answer (score 2):

Pardon the really late reply, but how about using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)? I'm looking for the link which provides you more information as I'm typing this, but Highcharts provides a server-side 'export' feature. What it basically does is it allows you to download a copy of an image without actually requiring a browser.

I implemented this feature so that I could take take request parameters, query a data-store, plot those numbers using Highcharts to a desired graph and embed those results in an email (and of course, send the email out to the recipients).

More information here: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/52-serverside-generated-charts

AND

here: https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export