# Launch jsdom from Rhino on Java

Tags: java, javascript, d3.js, rhino, jsdom

I'm following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677559/hybrid-server-side-java-and-client-side-javascript-charting-library):

I managed to run simple `JavaScript` code from [Rhino Engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) on Java.

But when it comes to [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), for example:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

as you can see `d3` requires DOM to be available on first place.

So, for that reason [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) is supposed to be the solution.

But `JSDOM` happens to be depended on [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html)

From `RequireJs` site:

> The **r.js** file allows you to run the optimizer as well as run modules
>   in Node, **Rhino** or xpcshell.

Then my Java Rhino code look like this:

```
FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("lib/r.js");
FileReader fr2 = new FileReader("lib/jsdom.js");
engine.eval(fr1);
engine.eval(fr2);
```

But for now I end up having an error like this:

> ReferenceError: "arguments" is not defined.

Then I found [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074836/resolving-modules-using-require-js-and-java-rhino):

Then my code look like this:

```
cx.evaluateReader(sharedScope, new FileReader("lib/r.js"), "require", 1, null);
cx.evaluateReader(sharedScope, new FileReader("lib/loader.js"), "loader", 1, null);
cx.evaluateReader(sharedScope, new FileReader("lib/jsdom.js"), "loader", 1, null);
```

> Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet

That basically means that `jsdom.js` itself is referencing to:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var URL = require('url');
```

So, it seems I just need to download all of them.

But [fs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) - is about **File System**. That means that it depends on NodeJs **native** implementation. Which is not good for my attempt **to be on plain java & plain js side**.

**Update:**

For now I'm doing my research in this direction:

```
https://github.com/nodyn/jvm-npm
http://nodyn.io/
```

**The question is:** How can I load JSDOM to Rhino to let D3.js to generate my SVG?

**Once more:** Java Rhino -> D3.JS -> JSDOME -> RequireJS -> **FS** => SVG ?

**"Or"** : [How Mozilla Rhino can use nodejs "fs" module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560360/how-mozilla-rhino-can-use-nodejs-fs-module)

I know I can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), but I'm looking or something that is Java-sticky. More lightweight, with no external processe launching involved.

Comment: Ever get this going?

Answer (score 1):

[`JsDom`](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) might be a bad option since it relies on so many internal features of Node and Google's V8 JavaScript engine. [Env.JS](http://www.envjs.com/) should be a better option but if it doesn't work then you're probably out of luck. It might not work because it's essentially a frozen project with last release in 2010. You'll have to either run your JavaScript in [Node](http://nodejs.org/) or [Phantom](http://phantomjs.org/), or generate SVG with Java-based solutions like [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/).

By the way `require` in JsDom is not the same as `require.js` but [a build-in Node.js function](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using [Domino](https://github.com/fgnass/domino) as a DOM environment. Look here (http://jazdw.net/content/server-side-svg-generation-using-d3js) for details. Reading comments section would be also helpful