# How Mozilla Rhino can use nodejs "fs" module?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, rhino

Let's say I have `my.js` file that has dependency on `nodejs` [fs module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). Like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

**The question:** How can I load Core NodeJS module like "FS" in My Mozilla Rhino Java Code to be able to run `my.js` that depends on it ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this. `fs` module just a wrapper for native bindings built into `node.js` itself.
There are some thoughts flying in the sky of `node.js` community about being able to use different JS engines inside `node.js` but I don't think we will see this in the near future.

Comment: some related links I'm looking at: https://github.com/nodyn/jvm-npm
http://nodyn.io/

Comment: Looks promising but, again, you can't load native `node.js` modules, you can only require them if they were implemented in `jvm-npm/nodyn.io`. They are not modules in regular way. BTW, there is ticket for that: https://github.com/nodyn/nodyn/issues/26

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own fs.js, only implementing the functions you need. Here is a start:

```
exports.readFile = function(file, enc, callback) {
  try {
    text = readFile(file, enc);
    callback(null, text);
  }
  catch (e) {
    callback(e, null);
  }
}
```

I've used this together with jvm-npm.

Comment: How would that work when `fs.js` requires Node's built-in native functions for file access?

Comment: The fs module *is* Node's native file access. That's not available on Rhino, so you have to write your own.

Comment: `fs.js` is not written in native code.